# SignalR web app, laptop server load test

Tags: javascript, web, signalr, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm creating a webapp that will be hosted locally on a laptop that should be capable of interacting with multiple clients via Signalr.  The idea is to have a laptop host all of the client interactions connected through a wireless network.  The page is built with .Net 4.5/MVC3/JQuery/SignalR.  I've been able to connect with about 6-8 clients without issue, but I'd like to know how far I can take it.  Is there any advice on how I can stress test the system? I hope to host about 20-40 client off of a single laptop, is this doable with the specs below?

Laptop Specs:
Processor:4th Generation Intel Core i7-4700MQ Processor (2.4 GHz 1600MHz 6MB)
Operating System:Windows 8.1 64
Graphics:Intel® HD Graphics 4600
Memory:8.0GB PC3-12800 DDR3 SDRAM 1600 MHz

Answer (score 0):

Make your own script rather than using any tool for signalr performance monitoring.

I used Gatling tool as framework(for to create multiple virtual users i.e. multithreading) and attached my load testing script written in java(java signalr client) to it and it worked very nice it is light weight and you can easily increase users! I tested up to 200 users!

please specify in comment if you want help in deciding performance(load and stress) test plan as it is key point in any performance test!